# Reading an HTM file with images, to create email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code that creates emails from Excel. Everything works, except the image I have on the .htm file that becomes the email body.

I write the email in Word and save it as a web page, filtered. Then I use this code to read the entire file into a string and put it in .HTMLBody.

```
Dim strLine As String
Open strBody For Input As #1
strBody = ""
Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strLine
    strBody = strBody & vbCrLf & strLine
Loop
Close #1
```

In the finished email, my image has the error

> "the linked image cannot be displayed..."

If I open a new mail window in Outlook and insert the .htm file as text (no need to save it or do anything else), then the image is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook uses Word to render the images, and Word does not support embedded (`src="data:image"`) images. You need to attach the image as a file, set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property on the attachment (`Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`), and make sure your HTML refers to the image through the `src=cid:xyz` attribute (where xyz is the value of the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property).

`PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F`